# Similar to connecting to remote computer using WSManagement, how to do it through powershell terminal

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am connecting to the remote windows machine to execute powershell scripts using WSManagement method.I am creating a runspace using WSManagement ConnectionInfo object.Then using the runspace for the powershell object.Then using the powershell object I am invoking scripts with 
`Powershell.Invoke()` command.

How to do this through the powershell terminal?

Comment: Is your question about how to do what your C# program does but by a user interactively at a PowerShell console?  If so, take a look at `Enter-PSSession` (somewhat similar to SSH) or `Invoke-Command` (somewhat like psexec.exe).

Comment: My script is present in my local machine. But If I do Enter-PsSession,I will enter into the powershell terminal of the remote computer.But then how to execute the script which is present in the local machine?

Answer (score 1):

I must be misunderstanding this, because it looks like you're asking for the [Invoke-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) cmdlet, which is the first result you'd get in a "powershell remote" google search.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock { get-disk }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -FilePath .\test.ps1
```

Comment: I wanted if this is the same as doing powershell.invoke() from a C# program?

Comment: As far as I know, `Invoke()` is the method used to execute the pipeline, which is equal to pressing enter in a terminal. The commands and script that you add in c# before running `Invoke()` is what matters.  The sample above is terminal-way of running a script on a remote computer, using the same cmdlet that Keith Hill suggested for you in c# in your earlier question.